# Error "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" on Select with ODBC Command

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odbc, data-access

I'm trying to execute a query against an Oracle DB using ODBC in .NET and am getting the following error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

However, the SQL statement is definitely correct, and I can execute it successfully from Oracle SQL Developer.  The query itself looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(SCHEMA.PKG.SPNAME('PARAMS'));
```

Another simple query works fine:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SCHEMA.MYTABLE
```

It looks like something with the former, where it's using a package in the query and causing something to break.  The error indicates that it's not properly ended, but it has a semi-colon and correct braces, so it seems something else is going on.

If I remove the trailing semi-colon, I get an error with no message.

My C# code is basic and looks like this:

```
using (var connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = commandText;

        connection.Open();
        var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
        connection.Close();

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

When using the Oracle library for .NET, it works when I remove the trailing semi-colon.  If I keep that in place, the same error about the SQL command not being properly ended comes up.

It seems like this query *should* work with ODBC.  Is there anything I need to differently to get it working, or is using the Oracle Managed Data Provider the only way?

Comment: what version of the OracleDataClient are you using..

Comment: Same situation here.
With a distant Oracle 11g db, it is ok to have semicolon or multiple statements in a single query execution ; whereas with a local Oracle 18c db it is not allowed...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From my experience, I have noticed several instances where a semicolon will break the query, such as JasperSoft Studio and the cx_Oracle Python module. I know very little about ODBC vs OracleDataClient, but I would imagine this is a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use ODBC I would actually do something like this using the OracleDataClient

```
var strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TABLE(SCHEMA.PKG.SPNAME('PARAMS'));";
using (OracleConnection connStr = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{         
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(strSQL, connStr))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //change the ExecuteScalar to fit the proper call
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I am using Oracle SQL Developer version 21.  My query worked fine in SQL Developer with the semicolon at the end, but when I put it in the C# code, it failed with the error you're reporting.  Once I took out the semicolon in the code, then the query worked.

My guess is that the Oracle classes in the code may be automatically including the semicolon behind the scenes, so the one we are adding was essentially resulting in duplicate semicolons like this:

```
SELECT * FROM YourMomsTable;;
```